# Solaris - My process listening on all the interfaces but other processes listening on localhost:6011

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, solaris, tcplistener

My server program is designed to listen on all the interfaces and it is listening working also.

One strange behavior is happening. It means port conflict with sshd process. Because I need to make my application and sshd to listen on same port range.(ex: 6000 - 6100)

## MyProg code:

```
   MyPort = 6011;

   #if TARGET_HAS_IPV6_SUPPORT

   /* IPv6 socket */
   {

        struct addrinfo *ai = NULL;

        r = ipw_getaddrinfo("::", NULL, AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, AI_PASSIVE, &ai);
        if (r == 0)
        {
          Create_listen_socket(&ai, IpcMyPort);
        }
    }
   #endif

    {
        struct addrinfo ailocal = { 0 };
        struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };

        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        ailocal.ai_family = AF_INET;
        ailocal.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        ailocal.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        ailocal.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        ailocal.ai_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        ailocal.ai_addr = (struct sockaddr *)&sin;
        Create_listen_socket(&ailocal, MyPort);
    }


Create_listen_socket(struct addrinfo *ai,
                     unsigned int MyPort)
{

    SOCKET fd = INVALID_SOCKET;

    while (ai != NULL)
    {
        fd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
            if (fd == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                Exit()
                break;
            }

            switch (switch (sa->sa_family)
            {
                case AF_INET:
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa;
                    sin->sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
                }
                break;

                #if TARGET_HAS_IPV6_SUPPORT 
                case AF_INET6:
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in6 *sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa;
                    sin6->sin6_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
                }
                break;

                #endif 
            }

            if (ipw_bind(fd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) < 0)
            {

               exit();
               Break;
            }
            else
            {

                r = ipw_listen(fd, IPC_MAX_LISTEN_COUNT);
             }

        ai = ai->ai_next;
    }
}
```

Following is the output of "sudo lsof -i -P | grep :60"

---

:: :: ::

sshd     23038 fin22495   11u  IPv4 0x60026f7c740      0t0  TCP
localhost:6011 (LISTEN)

myProg     23108     root    4u  IPv6 0x60026e46000      0t0  TCP *:6011
(LISTEN)

myProg     23108     root    5u  IPv4 0x6002658e3c0      0t0  TCP *:6011
(LISTEN)

---

If you see, the sshd daemon is listening on same port 6011 but on local host interface. but my program is listening on *.6011.

How to make sure myProg listening on "localhost:6011" along with *:6011 and if already some process is listening on "localhost:6011" how to detect it. It happens in Solaris.

Please let me know your views.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: Can you post code that shows how your program binds your socket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have done here because sshd should normally be listening on port 22, not 6011.  The first process opening the port will get exclusive access.  There are good, security-related reasons for this being so. See the tcp(7P) manpage for details - look for SO_REUSEADDR and SO_EXECLBIND.

Answer (score 0):

> If you see, the sshd daemon is listening on same port 6011 but on local host interface. but my program is listening on *.6011.
>
> How to make sure myProg listening on "localhost:6011" along with *:6011 and if already some process is listening on "localhost:6011" how to detect it. It happens in Solaris.

Your application's port numbers conflict with ports used by ssh X-forwarding. Change your port numbers and be done with that.

Comment: I explained to you already that if one process (i.e. sshd) is listening to a address+port you can't re-open the same address+port in another process.  If you want to detect it, explicitly open the address+port rather than wildcarding the address.